# How do you display Image Properties tab in Blender 3?

Tags: image, empty

How do you display Image Properties tab in Blender 3 ?

Thank you[image]

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure to understand, it looks like you're showing how to display it, is it missing in 3.0?

Comment: No I saved a picture I found on Google in order to illustrate what I want to display

Comment: It's Blender 3.3.1

Comment: I found the solution, it's because I import an Image as plane instead of a Reference, whats is the difference ?

Comment: oh ok..................        ;)